# Backbutton that goes back two or more Controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, back-button

I know that overriding the back button functionality is not considered a good user design. However I have process, at which at some point going back would'nt make any sense. Instead I would like the user to go back two or more controller

So within certain ViewControllers, clicking the back-button should trigger the pop of several ViewControllers, not just the one in front. I tried around with subclassing the NavigationController and overriding the popViewController-Method:

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([[self.viewControllers lastObject] class] == [MyCOntroller class]){
        [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; // pop once

        return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated]; // pop twice
    } else {
        return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    }
}
```

However I get problems, where the NavigationTopBar is not in sync anymore withe the ViewController being in front. Anybody ran into the same issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did u try using

```
popToViewController:animated:
```

> Pops view controllers until the
>   specified view controller is at the
>   top of the navigation stack.

Maybe u can have custom back buttons for such view controllers and then try

```
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed
{
[yourNavigationcontroller popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add left bar button.

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButton_clicked)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
[leftBarButton release];
```

And

```
-(void)backButton_clicked {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //or pop to special view controller
    //[self.navigationController popToViewController:specVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: The navigationItem has a property "backBarButtonItem". If you're using this the button looks like the normal arrow. You would create a "normal" UIBarButtonItem which looks in no sense like the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to delete the viewcontrollers you want to skip from the Navigation stack. In example below, you go back 2 view controllers:

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:[allViewControllers count]-2]; // 2 means last but one
self.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
```